# Show assembly version on webpage of non-MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

We have a webapplication which doesn't use MVC. This webapplication is already using an Assembly.cs. In my C# code I can get the version number of the webapplication, but how to get it in the webpage (.cshtml)?

I tried using

```
@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();
```

but it returns

```
t0cxczo0, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Not something which looks familiar.

When I use

```
@typeof(MyApp.Application).Assembly.GetName()
```

It compiles fine, but at run-time I get

```
"Cannot find namespace MyApp"
```

MyApp is the name of my application and Application is one of my classes.

I also tried

```
@System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(MyApp.Application).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion
```

But that also returns the "Cannot find namespace MyApp" error.

My webapplication uses some other home-made binaries which are reused across other webapplications. When I use

```
@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName()
```

I'm getting the name and version of the other assembly that is handling the template stuff. So I'm getting close ;)

When I use

```
@System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName()
```

I get a "Template Execution" error

When I use

```
@HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance
```

I'm getting an error about HttpContext doesn't exists.

Please advice how to do this should-be-easy task.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this?

in your usings

```
using System.Reflection
using System.Diagnostics
```

Then in your c# code

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fileVersionInfo.ProductVersion;
```

that's what we're currently using in one of our applications. We then take the variable "version" and assign it to either a control (webforms) or to a ViewBag variable.

If you need to pass it to/from an ajax request I would suggest using a webmethod in your c# code.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentAssembly()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
    string version = fileVersionInfo.ProductVersion;
  return version;
}
```

Then calling it via the client side to make it available to your page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentAssembly() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentAssembly",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);//you can replace this with code to populate an html element
}
</script>
```

Further explanation: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: I have no problems in getting the version in my C# classes. The problem is how to get it from the classes to my webpage. We don't use any controls on our webpages. We load the needed data using AJAX and parse them using KnockOut.js I'm not familiar with the ViewBag variable. Currently we're not using it.

Comment: ahh okay I didn't see the part where you said you're  not using MVC. Viewbag variables won't help you then. The other suggestion would be to use a webmethod to pass the string from your c#.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

This will allow you to pass from your c# code to javascript.

Comment: I understand how to get the version using an ajax call. I'd rather not use that because I want to use the version number in the header of my html to prevent my css and js files to be cached: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css?v=@(version)" type="text/css" /> 

I can't believe it is not possible to get the assembly version of my running webapp in the webpage.

Comment: it's in a cshtml page correct? Can you not call it through razor syntax?

Comment: the first part of the code i posted should be able to be used in razor.
@ using System.Reflection
@ using System.Diagnostics

Then surround the assembly code with an @ {} use the variable to populate in the page.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff for all your help. As you can see in my first post I'm already using Razor Syntax.  @System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() is returning the Razor assembly. I need to get my own assembly. I understand it is very difficult what I want so I will fallback to using a hard-coded string with the version number, in every cshtml file ;(

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most generic option but the following code is working in my case:

```
var uri = new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase);
var baseDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(uri.LocalPath);
if (baseDir != null)
{
    var appLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDir, "MyApp.dll");
    version = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(appLocation).FileVersion;
}
```

Only because GetCallingAssembly is another dll which is in my bin folder.